# Xcode: Extra tokens at end of #ifdef directive

Tags: xcode, token, warnings

This little peace of code

```
#ifdef QA || DEBUG

do something

#endif
```

creates the following error:

> Extra tokens at end of #ifdef directive

I tried removing one pipe, not working. Google only shows similar questions for cpp with irrelevant answers.

Any idea?

Comment: Try to insert a newline after `#ifdef`.

Comment: @the4kman not working :(

Comment: `#ifdef` expects a single macro name to be tested.  Use `#if` and the `defined` operator for complex conditions (e.g. testing two macros): `#if defined(QA) || defined(DEBUG)` is probably what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
#if defined(A) || defined(B)
// do stuff
#endif
```

or nested condition

```
#ifdef A
#ifdef B
    // do stuff
#endif
#endif
```